# React MUI Table - How to add Custom Component inside a row cell?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI Table (not Data Grid).
I need to have a column cell with Images, and another column with Action buttons.

I have been searching a lot, but I found only examples to achieve that with DataGrid. With normal MUI Table, I couldn't find anything helpful. And the documentation doesn't seem to cover these cases: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-table-images-component-d4pnx0?file=/demo.tsx:724-756) I have a working codeSandbox.

The payload will be similar to this one:

```
export const mockedProducts = [
  {
    productName: "Product name 1",
    code: "PN1",
    id: 324523,
    images: [
      "http://placekitten.com/200/300",
      "http://placekitten.com/500/370",
      "http://placekitten.com/1200/700",
      "http://placekitten.com/600/1200",
      "http://placekitten.com/300/170",
      "http://placekitten.com/3500/2500",
      "http://placekitten.com/200/1100"
    ],
  },
...
];
```

**Question 1)**
How can I create a custom component that renders the images inside the cells in the `Images` column?

I tried to change the `Images` column definition to a paragraph, but it gets ignored and the list of URLs still appear:

```
  {
    id: "images",
    label: "Images",
    minWidth: 170,
    align: "right",
    render: (row) => (
      <p>
        <img src={row[0]} />
      </p>
    ),
    format: (row) => (
      <p>
        <img src={row[0]} />
      </p>
    ),
  },
```

**Question 2:**
How can I create a column with two buttons (accept, deny)?
This column will not arrive from backend. There is no object value for "actionButtons" in the `const mockedProducts`. Also should this column be added to `const columns: readonly Column[]` specifications?

Answer (score 0):

I continue the implementation of the `render` function for you

```
  {
    id: "images",
    label: "Images",
    minWidth: 170,
    align: "right",
    render: (values: string[]) => (
      <>
        {Object.values(values).map((value) => (
          <img src={value} alt="" />
        ))}
      </>
    )
  }
```

However some images displayed are too big (as you chose them like this). So you'll have to manage to make them smaller or choose other images.

### Complete code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TablePagination from "@mui/material/TablePagination";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import { mockedProducts } from "./mockedProducts";

interface Column {
  id: "productName" | "id" | "images" | "actionButton";
  label: string;
  minWidth?: number;
  align?: "right";
  format?: (value: number) => string | React.ReactElement;
  render?: (value: string[]) => React.ReactElement;
}

const columns: readonly Column[] = [
  { id: "productName", label: "Product Name", minWidth: 170 },
  {
    id: "id",
    label: "Id",
    minWidth: 170,
    align: "right",
    format: (value: number) => <b>value.toLocaleString("en-US")</b>
  },
  {
    id: "images",
    label: "Images",
    minWidth: 170,
    align: "right",
    render: (values: string[]) => (
      <>
        {Object.values(values).map((value) => (
          <img src={value} alt="" />
        ))}
      </>
    )
  },
  {
    id: "actionButton",
    label: "Action Buttons",
    minWidth: 170,
    align: "right",
    format: (value: number) => value.toFixed(2)
  }
];

const rows = mockedProducts;

export function PendingProducts() {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(10);

  const handleChangePage = (event: unknown, newPage: number) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    setRowsPerPage(+event.target.value);
    setPage(0);
  };

  return (
    <Paper sx={{ width: "100%", overflow: "hidden" }}>
      <TableContainer sx={{ maxHeight: 440 }}>
        <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              {columns.map((column) => (
                <TableCell
                  key={column.id}
                  align={column.align}
                  style={{ minWidth: column.minWidth }}
                >
                  {column.label}
                </TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {rows
              .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
              .map((row) => {
                return (
                  <TableRow hover role="checkbox" tabIndex={-1} key={row.code}>
                    {columns.map((column) => {
                      const value = row[column.id];
                      console.log("\n\n");
                      return (
                        <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align}>
                          {column.format && typeof value === "number"
                            ? column.format(value)
                            : column.render && value instanceof Array
                            ? column.render(value)
                            : value}
                        </TableCell>
                      );
                    })}
                  </TableRow>
                );
              })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      <TablePagination
        rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 25, 100]}
        component="div"
        count={rows.length}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        page={page}
        onPageChange={handleChangePage}
        onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
      />
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possible way:**

You can create a custom Row component and use it to render the rows to fit your needs:

```
// Function to create rowData, so we don't have to mess with attributes
const createData = (name: string, calories: number, icon: string) => {
  return {
    name,
    calories,
    icon
  }
}
// Custom row component
const Row = (props: { row: ReturnType<typeof createData> }) => {
  // ** Props
  const { row } = props

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell></TableCell>
        <TableCell component='th' scope='row'>
          {row.name}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align='left'>{row.calories}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align='right'>
          <IconButton size='small'>
  // In my case I used custom library for this so i can import icons easier but you can import icon in any way you like
            <Icon icon={row.icon} />
          </IconButton>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

const rows = [
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 'tabler:activity'),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 'tabler:address-book-off'),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 'tabler:adjustments-star'),
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 'tabler:alpha'),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 'tabler:app-window-filled')
  ]
```

Now you can use this row to render your table:

```
const CustomTable = () => {
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table aria-label='collapsible table'>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell />
            <TableCell sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'start', alignItems: 'center', gap: '5px' }}>
              Name
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align='left'>Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align='right'>Icon </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map(row => (
            <Row key={row.name} row={row} />
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  )
}

export default CustomTable
```